# Websphere: add shared shared library to cluster

Tags: websphere, classloader

I need to add a shared library to Websphere cluster.
I have used the following approach - modified setupCmdLine.bat file this way

```
SET WAS_EXT_DIRS=%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%WAS_HOME%\classes;%WAS_HOME%\lib;%WAS_HOME%\installedChannels;%WAS_HOME%\lib\ext;%WAS_HOME%\web\help;%ITP_LOC%\plugins\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\runtime;%EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR%
```

This makes it possible to add custom jars to %EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR% folder.
But this works on a single server.
How do I do it to entire cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have not modified `startupCmdLine`. It is not the correct way in the cluster nor in the single server. Configure you shared library via admin console `Environment > Shared libraries`. If you want to associate that library with the cluster, you can select correct cluster in the Scope combo. Of course you will need to create directory with your shared jars on each node that is a member of the cluster and associate it with your application or server.

**Update**
To create server classloader go to  `Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Java and Process Management > Class loader` and create new classloader, then attach library to it.

See also:

- [Shared library collection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ucws_rsharedlib.html?lang=en)
- [Class loader collection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rclassloader.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)
- [Configuring class loaders of a server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_classload_server.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-5-1&lang=en)

Comment: I need classes from %EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR% to be loaded by single class loader, common for all the applications. When we use EXT_DIRS it works this way. How will it work with Shared libraries?

Comment: @mik You need to associate it with the server, not application. Details on on the same page. After you create library, you need to define new classloader and associate it with library and server. See added links.